# C# finding percent of matched words between two string

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, compare

I have a single string that i want to compare against a list of strings to find the best match.

For example,

```
string search = "Orange Black Red One Five"
```

the List of strings could contain the following

```
l[0] = "Orange Seven Three Black"
l[1] = " Nine Eight Seven Six"
l[2] = " Black Blue Purple Red Five Four Nine Ten"

l[0] contains 2 matches
l[1] contains 0 matches
l[2] contains 3 matches
```

so the program would choose l[2] as the best match, with a 60% match.
How would I compare two strings like this?

Comment: Split your search string into an array.  Then check out the `Regex.Matches` method here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Split `l[i]`, for each word, loop each word in `search` (as an array) and count the matches, storing the index of the highest one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    var s = search.Split(new string[] { " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var res1 = (from string part in l
        select new
        {
            list = part,
            count = part.Split(new char[] {' '}).Sum(p => s.Contains(p) ? 1 : 0)

        }).OrderByDescending(p=> p.count).First();

    Console.Write(res1.count);
```

Comment: Is it possible to compare two rich textbox  data and possible to get count of missing words and newly added words and modified words.Can you please tell me

Answer (score 2):

1. Split the strings in to arrays.
2. Determine the number of matches.
3. Divide.
4. ...
5. Profit!

Code:

```
double Compare(string a, string b)
{
    var aWords = a.Split(' ');
    var bWords = b.Split(' ');
    double matches = (double)aWords.Count(x => bWords.Contains(x));
    return matches / (double)aWords.Count();
}
```

Edit: Or, if you just want to get the match count...

```
int Matches(string a, string b)
{
    var aWords = a.Split(' ');
    var bWords = b.Split(' ');
    return aWords.Count(x => bWords.Contains(x));
}
```